# Show fixed number of characters in plotly legend followed by ellipsis?

Tags: python, plotly

I've been using `px.line()` to make interactive plots based on a unique ID but the unique ID is sometimes really long and the legend takes over the plot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df_plot, x="x", y="y", color="Unique_ID")
fig.show()
```

Is there a way I could only display the first 15 characters for example followed by ellipsis?
And if that is possible, could I get the full unique ID if I hover over the legend item?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite every trace name with `fig.for_each_trace`.

## Generate Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
     "x":np.arange(10),
     "y":np.random.randn(10)})

out = []
for i in range(3):
    df["Unique_ID"] = f"{i}"+"a"*14+"b"*5
    df["y"] += 1
    out.append(df.copy())
df_plot = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)
```

Basicallu every `Unique_ID` is one digit followed by 14 `a` and 5 `b`.

## Plot

```py
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df_plot, x="x", y="y", color="Unique_ID")
fig.for_each_trace(
  lambda trace: trace.update(name=trace.name[:15]))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works. Is it possible to get the full trace name if I hover over the legend object?

Comment: I guess that hover on legend should be another question. And apparently is not solved see [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-make-hover-text-on-legend-on-multiple-graphs-in-page/12484)